# how to change angular material theme with non material colors

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, frontend, themes

How to change angular material theme in existing project?
not: I want to use custom colors (non material colors) with hex cod,

primary: #f5375e;
accent: #4f058c;

thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this website to generate material theme scss and put it in your styles.
https://materialtheme.arcsine.dev